# Save multiple foreign keys in one model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rails-activerecord

I am new to Rails. Currently I am developing Rails 5 API.

There are two models.

```
BLOCK
block_name
--------------------------------
EMPLOYEE
name
email
block_ids (string)
```

Relationships

```
Employee
has_many: blocks

Block
belongs_to: user
```

The employee controls the blocks. When user creates employee he must specify which blocks this employee controls.

This is the body of post request.

```
{
    "first_name":"John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "email": "smith@gmail.com",
    "block_ids": "9,5,3"
}
```

So John Smith controls the blocks which ids are equal to 9, 5 and 3. I suppose this method is not good.

This is User controller's create action

```
def create
  @user = current_organization.employees.build(user_params)
  if @user.save!
     render json: @user
  else
     head :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

How to effectively store foreign keys to many blocks? What would you suggest me?

Comment: do you want a block to belong to only one user? or can one block be associated to many users?

Comment: one block can be associated to many users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have that `1xn` relationship (one employee has many blocks), you shouldn't use `block_ids` on employee. You should use `employee_id` on `block` model. Then add `belongs_to :employee` on `block.rb`.

However, if it's a `nxn` relationship (many to many), you have to create another model to do that relationship, like `EmployeeBlock`, which has `employee_id` AND `block_id`. something like:

```
class EmployeeBlock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :block
end
```

and on your employee.rb, something like:

```
has_many :employee_blocks
has_many :blocks, through: employee_blocks
```

And vice-versa for block.rb.

UPDATE:
 For creating that nxn relationship table, you can generate the model like this:

```
rails g model EmployeeBlock employee:references block:references
```

That way, it will create the table with the foreign keys and the belongs_to relationship.

For the form, in your case, I think it would be reasonable to have a form for your user with the nested association. That's a bit more complex, so I would suggest to take a look in this example, think it will make it clear:
http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/working-with-nested-forms-and-a-many-to-many-association-in-rails-4/

Comment: Thanks Ronan for the answer. That would be better if I will use the nxn. But how I should make a good body of post request that it will be understood which blocks the employee controls?

Comment: should I make migrations for EmployeeBlock model?

Comment: @ZhunissaliShanabek updated the question with some more information. Good luck!